# Focus Only On Input and Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to only allow focus on certain elements, such as input and button? For example, if the user is focused on an input field, and they click off somewhere else on the page, that input retains focus. But if the user clicks  another input or button, that new element gets focus.

I have attempted to achieve this by `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.PreventDefault()`, however, the elements still seem to lose focus.

My current attempt looks like:

```
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON' || event.target.tagName !==  'INPUT') {
        event.stopPropagation(); 
        event.preventDefault(); 
    } 
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: They are not wrong, both will work, the difference is that he is using bitwise.

Comment: @M.Doye Actually this is the better way to do it. They are strict comparison operators i.e: also checking type (boolean, string or integers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stop the focus lost, what you can do is programmatically put focus back only.

```
var last_focus_element;

$(document).on("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON' && event.target.tagName !==  'INPUT') {
        $(last_focus_element).focus();
    } 
});

$('input,button').on('blur', function() {
  last_focus_element = this;
});
```

**[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/1nu3hgpL/)**

Comment: Ah, ok. I knew this was an option, but I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can work with a global variable to cache the last element with had the focus to reset it after another element than `input` or `button` is clicked:

```
var $focus_el;

$(document).on("click", function (event) {
    var $this = $(event.target);
    if(!$this.is("input") && !$this.is("button")){
        $focus_el.focus();
    }
});

$('input, button').on('focus', function(){
    $focus_el = $(this);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e454wsny/)

**Reference**

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

[event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: Ah, ok. I knew this was an option, but I thought there might be a better way.